# Why doesn't SpeedTest.net Upload work in Windows when using a Debian-router?

Tags: iptables, router, upload, pppoe

There is a FTTx connection.
I connect ISP cable to the WindowsXP pc, setup PPPoE.
SpeedTest.net shows normal Upload / Download.

Now I connect ISP cable to router with Debian 7.5 installed, set up network interfaces, routing. Second router interface is connected to LAN.
SpeedTest.net on Linux Mint17 machine shows normal Upload/Download.
On WindowsXP and Windows7 machines Download is normal, but Upload becomes idle after working for some milliseconds.

Why? How can I provide normal Upload on Windows machines?

eth0 connected to LAN XXX.XXX.XXX.0

eth1 connected to ISP

External IP: YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY

**Configs:**

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address XXX.XXX.XXX.11
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network XXX.XXX.XXX.0
        broadcast 192.168.100.255
        gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.1
        dns-nameservers DNS.DNS.DNS.DNS

allow-auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

allow-auto ppp1
iface ppp1 inet ppp
        provider dsl-provider
        pre-up /etc/network/if-pre-up
```

/etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider

```
unit 1

user *user*
pty "/usr/sbin/pppoe -I eth1 -T 80 -m 1452"

noipdefault
usepeerdns
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute

holdoff 15
maxfail 0
lcp-echo-interval 20
lcp-echo-failure 3

connect /bin/true
hide-password
noauth
persist
mtu 1492
mru 1492

noaccomp
default-asyncmap
```

/etc/network/if-pre-up

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp1 -s XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp1 -o eth0 -d XXX.XXX.XXX.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s XXX.XXX.XXX.111 -o ppp1 -j SNAT --to-source YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
```

Answer (score 2):

I answer to myself and everyone interested.
The Problem is nown as Path MTU Discovery Black Hole.
Problem can be solved in different ways, I have just changed in /etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider

```
pty "/usr/sbin/pppoe -I eth1 -T 80 -m 1412"
```